# How to remove custom attribute value from magento 2 using setup script?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, customer-attribute

In Magento 2.x,

If I have created a custom attribute and then need to remove that attribute and also need to remove that attribute value that is assigned to that entity.

How can I do programmatically (Using setup script)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try below code. If your module has already been installed then use UgradeData to remove the attribute.

if you removed a custom attribute using a script the value is automatically removed.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeData.php :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
            $this->removeCustomerAttribute($setup);
            $this->removeProductAttribute($setup);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }


    private function removeCustomerAttribute(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_attribute'
        );
    }

     private function removeProductAttribute(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_attribute'
        );
    }
}
```

change your module version (make sure to increase it) in

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.1"></module>
</config>
```